# What am I doing wrong with this C program?

Tags: c

I have the following code, and the only thing I can physically see it evaluating is line 18 which is the call to printf().  It doesn't go any further.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    int cylNum;
    double disp, pi, stroke, radius;
        pi = 3.14159;

    printf("Welcome to the Engine Displacement Calculator!\n");

    cylNum = scanf("Enter number of cylinders (then press enter): \n");

    stroke = scanf("Enter stroke: \n");

    radius = scanf("Enter radius: \n");

    disp = radius * radius * pi * stroke * cylNum;

    printf("Displacement is: %f", disp);

    getchar();
    printf("Press any key to exit!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For your convenience: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the variables you're trying to read should be parameters to "scanf()", not the result of scanf():

```
printf("Enter number of cylinders (then press enter): ");
scanf("%d", &cylNum);
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it was something simple!  I took a break from C a while ago and forgot a lot of stuff, like this.  :)  Thanks again, and I'll accept in eight minutes.

Comment: @Dustin L. - thank you.  And, as other posters have noted, it's also good practice (albeit sadly uncommon!) to check the return value of your "scanf()", to make sure you actually got all the inputs you were expecting.

Comment: @paulsm4 - Corrected the format in `scanf` for you - `cylNum` is an interger.

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` function is to read in values.

So the line

```
cylNum = scanf("Enter number of cylinders (then press enter): \n");
```

should be the following lines

```
printf("Enter number of cylinders (then press enter): \n");
scanf("%d", &cylNum);
```

You need to check the return value of `scanf` to make sure that it is 1, i.e. conversion has taken place.

So perhaps the code should read

```
do {
   printf("Enter number of cylinders (then press enter): \n");
} while (scanf("%d", &cylNum) != 1);
```

For the variables `disp, pi, stroke, radius` you need to use `"%lf"` in the `scanf` function instead of `"%d`.

See [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) and [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

Answer (score 0):

"scanf" doesn't take parameter like the way you are trying.

```
printf("Enter number of cylinders (then press enter): \n");
scanf(" %d", &cylNum);

printf("Enter stroke: \n");
scanf(" %lf", &stroke);
```

Comment: Not much point in inserting spaces before `%d` and `%lf`. These format specifiers will skip whitespace by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void) {

    int cylNum;
    float disp, pi, stroke, radius;
    pi = 3.14159;
    printf("Welcome to the Engine Displacement Calculator!\n\n");
    printf("Enter number of cylinders (then press enter): ");
    scanf("%d", &cylNum);
    printf("Enter stroke: ");
    scanf("%f", &stroke);
    printf("Enter radius: ");
    scanf("%f", &radius);
    disp = radius * radius * pi * stroke * cylNum;
    printf("Displacement is: %f\n\n", disp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could add checking that conversion has taken place.

Comment: Sure :-) But the OP does have to do some of the work himself, right? :-)

Comment: It is a Sunday (well here it is) after all.